# Javascript/jQuery Change CSS On Click Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make three different buttons that switch between three different images using the CSS display property (this is so all the images will load when the webpage loads). However, it is not working, and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/agt559e8/ -- My Code

```
function USradarChange1() {
    //document.getElementById("usradar1").src="weather/current-usradar.gif";
    $('#USradarChangeButton1').click(function() {
        $('#usradar1').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
        $('#usradar2').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $('#usradar3').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    });
}

function USradarChange2() {
    //document.getElementById("usradar2").src="weather/usradar-an12hour.gif";
    $('#USradarChangeButton2').click(function() {
        $('#usradar1').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $('#usradar2').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
        $('#usradar3').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    });
}

function USradarChange3() {
    //document.getElementById("usradar3").src="weather/usradar-an7day.gif";
    $('#USradarChangeButton3').click(function() {
        $('#usradar1').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $('#usradar2').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        $('#usradar3').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
    <a class="button" id="USradarChangeButton1">Current US Radar</a>
    <a class="button" id="USradarChangeButton2">US Radar 12 Hours</a>
    <a class="button" id="USradarChangeButton3">US Radar 7 Days</a>
</div>

<div id="imgcontainer">
    <img class="radar-img" id="usradar1" src="weather/current-usradar.gif" alt="Current US Radar">
    <img class="radar-img" id="usradar2" src="weather/usradar-an7day.gif" alt="Current US Radar">
    <img class="radar-img" id="usradar3" src="weather/usradar-an12hour.gif" alt="Current US Radar">
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues with your code. Firstly you define some functions which are never called so the event hooks within them are never bound, there are mis-matched braces and your fiddle does not include jQuery itself.

Those issues aside, your code can be improved by using DRY principles. Try this:

```
<div class="button-container"> 
    <a class="button" id="USradarChangeButton1" href="#usradar1">Current US Radar</a>
    <a class="button" id="USradarChangeButton2" href="#usradar2">US Radar 12 Hours</a>
    <a class="button" id="USradarChangeButton3" href="#usradar3">US Radar 7 Days</a>
</div>

<div id="img-container">
    <img class="radar-img" id="usradar1" src="http://trendting.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/giphy-225.gif" alt="Current US Radar" />
    <img class="radar-img" id="usradar2" src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/H3MXq3XT4z2ec/200_s.gif" alt="US Radar 12 Hours" />
    <img class="radar-img" id="usradar3" src="http://media.giphy.com/media/10Ocy3t9qoSOwE/giphy.gif" alt="US Radar 7 Days" />
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#img-container img').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/agt559e8/3/)

Note that this single `click` handler will now work for all `.button` elements, as they now relate to the required `div` via the `href` attribute.

Comment: Worked perfectly and helped me keep my script from being cluttered, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the 3 functions defined?It will not work then!

You need to put your jquery code in the `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#USradarChangeButton1').click(function() {
            $('#usradar1').css({
                'display': 'inline'
            });

            $('#usradar2').css({
                'display': 'none'
            });

            $('#usradar3').css({
                'display': 'none'
            });
        });

//BUTTON 2 CODE
//BUTTON 3 CODE

});
```

Comment: Also dont forget to include Jquery is your fiddle. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/agt559e8/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your handling code isn't being executed because they're in functions that are never called (`USradarChange3` and friends). You can either:

- Call the functions so that the binding code inside gets executed.
- or remove the functions so you don't need to call the functions for the binding to take place.

Also, the jsFiddle doesn't seem to add jQuery so that could also be a problem. And if jQuery *is* loaded, wrap everything in a `ready` handler. to make sure the elements are loaded prior to binding.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you got wrong here, first off you need to provide the jQuery library in jsFiddle
[take a look here](https://jsfiddle.net/powerphillg5/pjnfjrqt/1/)

Second: the functions you have aren't being called, therefor aren't binding the click handlers to the buttons.

Third: You need to do it after all the stuff is done loading so it should look more like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#USradarChangeButton1').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#usradar1').css({
        'display': 'inline'
    });
    $('#usradar2').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#usradar3').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

});


$('#USradarChangeButton2').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#usradar1').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#usradar2').css({
        'display': 'inline'
    });
    $('#usradar3').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
});


$('#USradarChangeButton3').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#usradar1').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#usradar2').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#usradar3').css({
       'display': 'inline'
    });
 });

})
```

Notice the `event.preventDefault()` this is being used to prevent the default behavior of links.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong; What you are currently doing is binding the function to the click once the user has clicked on the button.

What you need to do is bind those 3 functions when the DOM is ready.

```
$(function(){
    $('#USradarChangeButton1').click(function() {
        $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'inline'});
        $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'none'});
        $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'none'});
    });

    $('#USradarChangeButton2').click(function() {
        $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'none'});
        $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'inline'});
        $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'none'});
    });

    $('#USradarChangeButton3').click(function() {
        $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'none'});
        $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'none'});
        $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'inline'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the jQuery lib was missing in fiddle,
secondly I found syntax issues.

you have declared a function in which you have registered a 'click' event, which is not gonna work

Here are the 2 approaches that will help you to achieve your result

```
$('#USradarChangeButton1').click(USradarChange1);
$('#USradarChangeButton2').click(USradarChange2);
$('#USradarChangeButton3').click(USradarChange3);

function USradarChange1() {
    $('#usradar1').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
    $('#usradar2').css({ 'display': 'none'});
    $('#usradar3').css({ 'display': 'none'});
}


function USradarChange2()
{
    $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'none'});    
    $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'inline'});    
    $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'none'});
}

function USradarChange3()
{
    $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'inline'});
}
```

OR directly without declaring any function like this :

```
$('#USradarChangeButton1').click(function(){
    $('#usradar1').css({ 'display': 'inline' });
    $('#usradar2').css({ 'display': 'none'});
    $('#usradar3').css({ 'display': 'none'});
});

$('#USradarChangeButton2').click(function(){
    $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'none'});    
    $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'inline'});    
    $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'none'});
});

$('#USradarChangeButton2').click(function(){
    $('#usradar1').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('#usradar2').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('#usradar3').css({'display': 'inline'});
});
```

Hope it ll help you